# PS4 dead - will my saves be recoverable?

Tags: diablo-iii, technical-issues, ps4

My PS4 seems to be dead (I will explain what it is doing after I ask the question) but my question is: If I have to send it in for repairs and/or get a new one - will my data be completely wiped? Specifically I am worried / wondering about Diablo 3. Is my character (along with items) saved on the PS cloud or will all of that be lost?

Comment: AFAIK Diablo 3 stores the progress on Blizzard's servers. I only play the PC version not the PS4 version, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Console Versions can play offline.  It all depends what mode he was in and if he was logged in via b.net

Comment: Please only ask one question per question. Since the question about what might happen to your HDD has been answered, that's the question that I kept. That said, the clicking sounds are probably coming from your hard drive, so it is very much possible that the contents of that drive are already gone for good

Answer (score 1):

Diablo 3 on console unfortunately saves games to the hard drive. While Playstation 4 can automatically back up saves to the cloud, this will only happen if you have selected "automatic backup" previously. Your best bet to check would be to log in on a friends console, and simply see if you can retrieve anything.

If you have at all played previously on Xbox360 or PS3, you can use the save transfer utility to transfer over a backup of any older characters you may have played.